# Check both if the string is uppercase and if it's not empty in a prompt in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have to ask the user his surname and check if his input is not empty, plus I have to put his surname in an array within other values and put everything in alphabetical order. Since Javascript is case-sensitive I also want to transform the first letter of the surname put by the user in an uppercase letter. I tried with a do-while cycle and an if later, but it doesn't work.

```
var userSurname;

do {
    userSurname = prompt('Inserisci il tuo cognome');
} while (userSurname.length == 0);

if (userSurname == userSurname.toLowerCase()) {
    userSurname.toUpperCase();
}

surnameList.push(userSurname);
surnameList.sort();
console.log(surnameList);
```

Comment: The toUpperCase function returns a new string. It doesn't modify the original string..

Comment: I didn't know it, thanks..is there a method to transform an input in uppercase?

Comment: Yes, that function. Write `userSurname = userSurname.toUpperCase();`

Comment: @jarmod Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I see what you're trying to do - convert all the letters to upperacase. However, it looks like you are thinking about it in a bit too convoluted way. Try this:

```js
var userSurname = prompt('Inserisci il tuo cognome').toUpperCase();
console.log(userSurname)
```

In case you want to convert only the first letter to uppercase:

```js
var userSurname = prompt('Inserisci il tuo cognome');
userSurname = userSurname.slice(0, 1).toUpperCase() + userSurname.slice(1);
console.log(userSurname)
```

Comment: Thanks! The second option is exactly what I wanted! If I can ask, just to not copy and pasrte code, how does it works the `userSurname = userSurname.slice(0, 1).toUpperCase() + userSurname.slice(1);` thing. Why .slice and 0 and 1?

Comment: `userSurname.slice(0, 1)` is used to get the first letter in the string. It works like this: `userSurname.slice(<startLetterIndex>, <endLetterPosition>)` where index starts at 0 (not 1) and position starts at 1. `userSurname[0]` would work too.

Comment: While it would work generally, some browsers do not support indexing for strings, so slice is typically better in such cases.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* I understand what you're trying to achieve. This worked for me:

```js
let surnameList = [];
let userSurname;

do {
  userSurname = prompt('Inserisci il tuo cognome');
} while (userSurname == null || userSurname.trim().length === 0); // makes sure the string is not full of whitespaces

let fixedSurname = ''; // create a new variable to fix the name

for (let word of userSurname.split(' ')) {
  fixedSurname += word[0].toUpperCase() + word.slice(1).toLowerCase();
  fixedSurname += ' ';
} // capitalize the name: hello world -> Hello World

fixedSurname = fixedSurname.slice(0, fixedSurname.length - 1); // remove the extra space

surnameList.push(fixedSurname);
surnameList.sort();
console.log(surnameList);
```